# Why input textbox does not accept ASCII (Alt + ascii number) values?

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, keyboard, ascii

I was writing automation tool for testing our Webpages. I eventually came to know input textbox does not support ASCII value (like *Alt + 65* should type *A*).

```
<input name="somename" type="text"> //does not accept Alt + ASCII as input
```

I think this may be because of our own validations, then I check same with Stackoverflow's search box, but it also shows same behaviour.

Is it browser dependant, or HTML? How to enable taking ASCII input, without touching to actual HTML code?

I am currently using Chrome browser.

Comment: What is your operating system? E.g. ubuntu does not usually recognize `alt + 64` as `@`, it has another way of inputing such characters.

Comment: @JanLegner I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Did you install any addons recently? Tried emptying your browser cache? Interesting fact is that I tried to google your problem and although there are some, who have the very same problem, there is never a solution given :/

Comment: @JanLegner I always Google before coming to SO.

Comment: This seems to be about using a browser (possible due to issues with some add-on), not about programming as defined as the scope of SO. It might be on-topic at SuperUser but needs a different description and more details then.